# Upload to imgur java

Tags: java, image, upload, imgur

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to upload to imgur using java, does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you're likely to be best off using the [imgur api](http://code.google.com/p/imgur-api/).

The documentation for [uploading](http://code.google.com/p/imgur-api/wiki/ImageUploading) contains examples for Python and PHP that use cURL. It should be possible to adapt these to the [Java bindings for cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/), or other HTTP libraries such as [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/).

Answer (score 5):

1. Get a developer [key](https://imgur.com/register/api/).
2. Look at their [Image Upload API](https://api.imgur.com).
3. Use [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to create a [POST request](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html) and send:

   > - 'image' - A binary image file, base64 encoded string, or URL.
   > - 'key' - Your registered developer API key. Click here to register for a key.

Comment: If HttpClient is too overwhelmed, you could also just use `java.net.URLConnection` with `setDoOutput(true)` and write `image=...&key=...` to its `OutputStream`.

Comment: @BalusC I know your reply is super old but I'm just coming across it now and was wondering if you were willing to provide some code implementing this. I have my Imgur key as well as my binary image, I just can't for the life of me wrap my head around URLConnection.

Comment: @MeshulamSilk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! I'll be sure to have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try cURL. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) with great success for this sort of tasks. Read the `Submitting a form` in the [Getting started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) section, and you'll be done in no time.